# Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and the distance of any two points in $S$ is rational. Prove $S$ is a countable set.

Tags: complex-numbers, cardinals

$S$ is a subset of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, how do we prove that its countable?
isn't it trivial that $S$ will be countable if distance is rational, or is $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself a countable set, which is why $S$ is countable? If so, how do we prove $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a countable set?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not trivial, and of course we know that $\Bbb R^2$ is not countable.

HINT: Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points of $S$. For each $x\in S$ we know that $d(p,x)$ and $d(q,x)$ are rational, so $x$ lies on a circle of rational radius centred at $p$ and on a circle of rational radius centred at $q$.

- How many circles of rational radius centred at $p$ are there? How many centred at $q$?
- If $C_0$ and $C_1$ are circles with different centres, what is the largest possible cardinality of $C_0\cap C_1$?

**Added:** To see why it’s not trivial, note that if we gave $\Bbb R^2$ the discrete metric instead of the usual one, then $d(x,y)$ would be rational for every $x,y\in\Bbb R^2$: in that case $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$, and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$. Thus, in that case $S$ could be **any** subset of $\Bbb R^2$, countable or uncountable.

Comment: Beat me to it, haha.

Comment: Since you went so far as to add a remark explicitly explaining how it's nontrivial, would you say that this result is nontrivially nontrivial? Or, since it's a standard counterexample which (once learned about) is second-nature to consider, is it nontrivially trivially nontrivial? :P

Comment: @Noah: ÞÞÞttt!  :-)

Comment: Sadly, this method doesn't seem to resolve whether there is an $8$ point such set with no three of the points collinear and no four of the points cocircular.  :-(  (Of course, why would anyone expect this method to resolve such a question?...)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott will this mean that S will be a countable union of two countable sets, and hence be countable? The largest possible cardinality of C0 and C1 will be the smallest infinite cardinality, but I'm not entirely sure how this relates back to S being countable

Comment: @user915841: *Countable* means that its cardinality is either finite or the smallest infinite cardinality. The largest possible cardinality of the intersection of two different circles is actually a good deal less than $\aleph_0$, the smallest infinite cardinality: it’s $2$.

Comment: Can I ask one question: for fixed points $p, q\in S$, why $S$ is a subset of the intersection of $C_0$ and $C_1$? The cardinality of $C_0\cap C_1$ is at most $2\times card(\mathcal{Q}\times \mathcal{Q})$.

Comment: Also, we just show that for fixed pair $(p,q)$ that $d(p,x)$ and $d(q,x)$ are rational. But how do we ensure that $d(p,q)$ is rational?

Comment: @Hermi: $d(p,q)$ is rational by hypothesis, since $p,q\in S$. If $C_0$ and $C_1$ are circles in the plane with different centres, there are three possibilities for their intersection. They can be disjoint, in which case $|C_0\cap C_1|=0$. They can be tangent to each other, in which case $|C_0\cap C_1|=1$. And if neither of those is the case, then $|C_0\cap C_1|=2$. Thus, the largest possible cardinality of $C_0\cap C_1$ is $2$. It follows that $|S|\le 2|\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q|=\omega$, i.e., that $S$ is countable (which I suspect is what you had in mind in the first comment).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes! Thank you. That makes sense now.

Comment: @Hermi: You’re welcome.